# SQL merge two tables of different row count when join is not possible

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with below setup where `PurchaseId` has only **one record** where `ProductIds` has **one or more records**

```
DECLARE @PurchaseId TABLE ([Id] INT);

DECLARE @ProductIds TABLE ([Id] INT);

INSERT INTO @PurchaseId(Id) VALUES(1)

INSERT INTO @ProductIds(Id) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO @ProductIds(Id) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO @ProductIds(Id) VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO @ProductIds(Id) VALUES(4)
```

Is there a way how to merge those two tables with data of different row count to one table where row count would be row count of `@ProductIds`? Basically duplicate the `PurchaseId` value to every `ProductIds`

So the desired final table would be

```
foo | bar
----+-----
 1  |  1
 1  |  2
 1  |  3
 1  |  4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want a `cross join`?

```
select pu.id foo, pr.id bar
from @purchaseIds pu
cross join @productIds pr
```

Or, you may be looking to distribute existing purchases over products. If so, a method uses window functions:

```
select pu.id foo, pr.id bar
from (select pr.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from @productIds pr) pr
inner join (select pu.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from @purchaseIds pu) pu
    on pu.rn = pr.rn % pu.rn + 1
```